# How to generate a new var that contains an object by clicking on a button?

Tags: javascript, class, object, var

so what I am trying to do is to create a new object containing a team's information (name, league, players) every time a form is filled out and the respective button is clicked.

The team object is an instance of the class team. I am currently struggling with storing the generated team as a variable.

Unfotunately, the variable is overridden every time the button is clicked.

How do I solve this? Can I somehow create a dynamic variable name every time the button is clicked (e.g. the var name = team.name)? I want a new variable for every team that's created so I can always identify and access it.

Sorry, I am still quite a newby with JS. Cheers! :)

```
class team {
    constructor(teamname, teamleague, players) {
        this.teamname = teamname;
        this.teamleague = teamleague;
        this.players = [];

    }

var generatedTeamName = "";
var generatedTeamLeague = "";
var newteam = "";

var listofTeams =[];

$(document).ready(function(){
/* --- NEW TEAM ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

    $("#generateteam").click(function(){
      generatedTeamName = $('input[name="text-5"]').val();
      generatedTeamLeague = $('input[name="text-6"]').val();

      var storenewTeamhere = new team (generatedTeamName, generatedTeamLeague, []); 

    })
});
```

}

Comment: No, do not attempt to use dynamic variable names. What you actually want is store a collection of team objects, e.g. as an array. It looks like you even already created that array.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you want to consume stored team data, but there are many ways you can do this.

```
class Team {
  constructor(teamname, teamleague, players) {
    this.teamname = teamname;
    this.teamleague = teamleague;
    this.players = players;
  }
}

/* the array method */
const listOfTeams = [];

$("#generateteam").click(function () {
  let name = $('input[name="text-5"]').val();
  let league = $('input[name="text-6"]').val();
  let team = new Team(
    name,
    league,
    []
  );

  listOfTeams.push(team);

  // you can access the team as simply `team` here
});

// here you can access the teams by array index
// listOfTeams[i]

/* the object method */
const teams = {};

$("#generateteam").click(function () {
  let name = $('input[name="text-5"]').val();
  let league = $('input[name="text-6"]').val();
  let team = new Team(
    name,
    league,
    []
  );

  teams[name] = team;

  // you can access the team as simply `team` here
});

// you can now access the team by teamname
// teams['Some Team Name']
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick response. In either case, how would I acess my teams now and e.g. change or add variables (like players)? I think I still struggle a bit with grapsing the concept of objects and classes. cheers!

Comment: If you are using the second method, i.e. storing them in an object, you can access the `players` array by doing this `teams['Some Team Name'].players` and you can add players by doing `teams['Some Team Name'].players.push(player)`. Also, there's plenty of blogs out there that explain objects and arrays in javascript really well, you should try and give them a read. Secondly, if you have any programming experience at all, then JS objects are loosely like `dict`s in python and `HashMap`s in Java. If you don't, then doing a basic interactive tutorial online should help.